# How to link zClip to anchor tag inside repeater control in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater, zclip

I am using zClip Jquery plug in to copy some URL to clipboard. The SAMPLE code for zClip as below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#copy-description').zclip({
        path: 'zClip/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $('p#description').text()
    });
});
```

It works fine normally as a normal anchor tag and a normal paragraph. But I need the anchor tag to be in a repeater and I need to copy respective URL to clipboard `<%# Eval("URL") %>`. There will be n number of anchors and n number of URL to copy as repeater generates. I have tried few things I know but I can't make it worked. How can I solve out this problem?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptWebAddress" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptWebAddress_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p>
            <asp:Table runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server">
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("URL") %>' Target="_blank">Click Here</asp:HyperLink>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>Web link. Click it. Open in browser. Save as a bookmark.</asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow2" runat="server">
                    <asp:TableCell> <a style="text-decoration: underline;" id="copy-description" href="#">Copy</a> 
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>Web link as text. Copy and paste.</asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: will you be able to add a class like `zcopy` to the anchor

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks for your reply .. i didn't get what you mean. but i updated the questions. There will be x numbers of anchor as repeater generates and x number of URLs to copy.

Comment: will you be able to change `<a style="text-decoration: underline;" id="copy-description" href="#">Copy</a> ` to `<a style="text-decoration: underline;" id="copy-description" href="#" class="zcopy">Copy</a> `

Comment: Also where is the `p#description` element

Comment: @ArunPJohny Ahh .. sorry .. my poor ability to explain things. I didnt' actually want to copy that *p#description* I need to copy this <%# Eval("URL") %> that generates dynamically. There will be many anchors so I don't think adding a class would help

Comment: ok any way will you be able to make the dom change I suggested,ie adding the class attribute

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can add a class `zcopy` to the `Copy` element

```
$(function(){
    $('.zcopy').each(function(i,v){
        var el = $(v);
        el.zclip({
            path: 'zClip/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: el.closest('tr').prev().find('a').attr('href')
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks ... but I am abit lost what you are trying to do. I can certainly set `zcopy` class to the `copy` element. I put your code in but it doesn't seem to click for some reason. what else do I do? even i tried with just `copy: 'hello world'` and it doesn't click at all

Comment: can you type `$('.zcopy').length` in your browser console and see what is happening

Comment: It has 4 which is right. I tried to put an Alert after `el.zclip({` but that doesn't get hit. if I changed it to `el.click(function (e) {alert("hello world");});` then it clicked. Do you think that's anything to do with the anchor link being in the repeater or the table?

Comment: Hi .. i have done more research .. the issue is bigger than I thought .. it uses flash movies which don't align properly in a table element. There are many posts saying "zClip not work in table" .. I can't remove my table. I am given up using zClip. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do this. Good old fashion javascript will do:

```
<asp:TableCell>
   <a style="text-decoration: underline;" id="copy-description" href="#" onclick="CopyUrl(this, '<%# Eval("URL") %>';">Copy</a>
</asp:TableCell>
```

And your javascript function will look like this:

```
function CopyUrl(object, url) {
    object.zclip({
        path: 'zClip/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: url
    });    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. It doesn't work. I believe it's the same issue as the other answer doesn't work that the flash movie doesn't align properly in a table.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work for you. I did some more research on javascript copy to clipboard. In short it is not possible w/out the use of Flash. here is a good discussion on SO: [How to copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)